# Django 1.6 models.Manager Complaining about to many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use kwarg `field='unanswered=True'` in my model.manager but it is complaining about to many values to unpack. Not understanding why and what to do about it.

Model manager:

```
class ListAllObjectsManager(models.Manager):
    def date_search_threads(self, date1, date2, **kwargs):
        print kwargs["field"]
        date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%m-%d-%Y").date()
        date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%m-%d-%Y").date()
        date2 = date2 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return super(ListAllObjectsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
                kwargs["field"], **{'{}__range'.format(
                    kwargs["column"]): (date1, date2)})
```

View:

```
class StatisticsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'bot_data/stats.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        date1 = self.request.GET.get('search')
        date2 = self.request.GET.get('search_extra')
        if not date1 or not date2:
            date1 = "12-01-1999"
            date2 = "12-01-2050"
        context['unanswered_threads'] = ThreadVault.list_all_threads \
                .date_search_threads(date1, date2, field='unanswered=True',
                column="latest_post_date").count()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `kwargs["field"]` is just a string. Try

```
def date_search_threads(self, date1, date2, **kwargs):
    print kwargs["field"]
    date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1, "%m-%d-%Y").date()
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, "%m-%d-%Y").date()
    date2 = date2 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    param_filter = {'{}__range'.format(kwargs["column"]): (date1, date2)}
    if 'field' in kwargs:
        field = kwargs['field'].split('=')  
        param_filter[field[0]] = field[1]
    return super(ListAllObjectsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(**param_filter))
```

Or better, directly pass a dict in kwargs:

```
...
context['unanswered_threads'] = ThreadVault.list_all_threads \
        .date_search_threads(date1, date2, field={'unanswered': True},
        column="latest_post_date").count()
```

And

```
...
param_filter = {'{}__range'.format(kwargs["column"]): (date1, date2)}
param_filter.update(kwargs.get('field', {})
return super(ListAllObjectsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(**param_filter))
```